# Integer Square root of a number

Tags: algorithm, recursion, sml, smlnj, square-root

It's not that I don't understand how to find the integer square root of a number. I know several ways of finding them using Python and C++.

It's just that this algorithm is really messing with my brain. And having to write it in SML is another headache.

Please help me in understanding this algorithm. Do note that this should be using recursion:

> The integer square root of  is the integer  such that ²≤<(+1)².
> The integer square root can be computed using the following inductive process:
>
> 1. Compute the integer square root  of  =  div 4 recursively. We then have that ²≤<(+1)².
> 2. Since  and  are integers, we have that (+1)≤(+1)². We thus have (2)²≤4≤<4+4≤(2+2)².
> 3. Hence we have that the integer square root of  is either 2 or 2+1.
>
> Write a recursive ML program corresponding to the above algorithm.

Comment: recursion with memoisation. That's the way you want to go.

Comment: "Please help me in understanding this algorithm" is not a real question, because there can be no single authoritative answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The piece that is missing from the description is the so-called *base case* of the recursion. It is trivial, but necessary to specify: the integer square root of 0 is 0. By repeatedly recursing with a value that is one fourth (integer divison) of the current value, you'll eventually get to that base case.

I'm not fluent in SML, but I believe it should be something like this:

```
fun intSquareRoot 0 = 0
  | intSquareRoot n = 
    let 
      val m = n div 4 
      val i = intSquareRoot m
      val k = 2 * i + 1
    in 
      if k * k <= n then k
      else k - 1
    end;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much! I'll keep base cases in mind from now on.